# Python, Listening on two sockets at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am making a python server that should handle connection from remote hosts on port 9090 and connection only from localhost (a GUI sending data) on port 9091.
I think the problem is in socket.listen(backlog), because this blocks everything.
So there is a way to make socket1.listen(backlog) and socket2.listen(backlog) running at the same time?
Also, is it a good, and above all safe, idea to make a socket for receiving data from a GUI (written in Java)?

Comment: why not using thread? the first socket won't block the other socket.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague, but yes its possible, you need another thread, preferably a thread for each socket. Try wrapping the socket functionality in a new class, inherit that class from Thread and then just make a new class instance for each port

Comment: Are you using an existing python web server or writing your own? I wouldn't use a socket for receiving gui data personally. I think you are looking for `interprocess communications` such as D-Bus, XML-RPC and others.

Comment: Yes, its safe to send data from python on one socket and receive it in Java. Its also considered a good option for Inter-process communication which is what you are explaining that you are doing here

Comment: You can make `listen` / `accept` not block by setting `socket.setblocking(0)` on the listening socket(s).  Then you can use `select` to wait for events.  There are some details to take care of, but it should be fairly easy.  Of course, you can also use a library that does such stuff for you.  One option is twisted: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/.  See their echo server example (https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/#echoserver) to get started.

Comment: What python version are you using? What platform? I've been trying on various `python2` versions on `Windows`, `Centos`, `RedHat` and none of them was blocking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in C: [Listen to multiple ports from one server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15560336/584846)

and C++: [Create multiple listening sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22775149/584846)

so you should be able to do this in Python.

The only thing that would make this not safe is if your server performs a dangerous activity in response to the GUI, but you can probably add code to check and protect against hacks.

Comment: There is the possibility that someone spoof his ip address in 127.0.0.1 and send data to the Python Server pretending to be the GUI?

Comment: No, that is a special `loopback` address that only works on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `python2.7.3`, and as stated in my comment I couldn't reproduce the `listen` blocking issue.
Notes:

- for the simplicity's sake I am only using `IPv4` sockets
- I included `Python`'s prompter in the code to show that it didn't block
- regarding eventual security concerns: the socket (`s_local`) listening on 9091, only accepts connections from localhost (from other hosts will fail)

Here's a snippet from a *CentOS5* machine:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s_global = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s_global.bind(("", 9090))
>>> backlog = 0xFF
>>> s_global.listen(backlog)
>>> s_local = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s_local.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9091))
>>> s_local.listen(backlog)
>>>
```

and here's some output on the same machine:

```
netstat -an | grep 909
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9091              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

As seen, both *server* sockets are listening for connections.

Now, if something is wrong in my environments (some reading revealed that by default sockets *are* blocking by default), **after creating each socket**, you could add (as specified in one comment) the following line(s):

- for s_global

  ```
  s_global.setblocking(0)
  ```
- for s_local

  ```
  s_local.setblocking(0)
  ```

Now in order to **receive incoming connections** from both sockets, you should use `Python`'s [select module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) (used for async IO) **with no need for other threads**; your server app should constantly listen for connections, something like:

```
TIMEOUT = 1 #seconds
terminate = False # variable to be modified externally to end the loop
listening_sockets = [s_global, s_local]
while (not terminate):
    notified_socket_list = select.select(listening_sockets, [], [], TIMEOUT)[0]
    for notified_socket in notified_socket_list:
        incoming_socket, addr = notified_socket.accept()
        handle(incoming_socket, addr)
```

Note: worth being mentioned: *epoll*(`select.epoll`) is performance-wise preferred to *select*(`select.select`) but i haven't tried it yet.

Now, regarding the connections handling function(**handle**): if your server is designed only for educative purposes, you can leave it as it is, but if your server is designed to accept lots of simultaneous connections and lots of data exchange from/to each client, you should handle each connection in a separate **thread**(this is a general advice that doesn't apply to `Python` because of its [GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf), sometimes threads only slow things down)/**process** as done in [SocketServer.py - part of Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html).

@Edit1 - reply to 1st comment:

It's simple, all you have to do is modify a little bit the *inner* `for` loop:

```
    for notified_socket in notified_socket_list:
        incoming_socket, addr = notified_socket.accept()
        if notified_socket == s_global:
            handle_global(incoming_socket, addr)
        else:
            handle_local(incoming_socket, addr)
```

or you can use my original solution and do the differentiate the connections in **handle**: the `addr` argument contains the (local) port that the socket connected to; you can test it and depending on its value (9090 or 9091) handle the connection differently.